Is it possible to realize the relationship between pancha mahabhootas and pancha tanmatras?
According to Sanatana Dharma, there is a relationship between the pancha mahabhootas (Earth, Wind, Space, Water, and Light/Fire) and the pancha tanmatras (sound, touch, form, taste, smell). There are several answers 1, 2 in our site that are related to this relationship and for quick reference, I am including the following excerpt:

Bhishma said, '..... Earth, Wind, Space, Water, and Light forming
the fifth, are the great essences. These are (the causes of) the
origin and the destruction of all creatures. The bodies of living
creatures (both subtile and gross), O bull of Bharata's race, are the
result of the combination of the virtues of these five. Those virtues
(whose combinations produce the bodies of creatures) repeatedly start
into existence and repeatedly merge into the original cause of all
things, viz., the Supreme Soul. From those five primal essences are
created all creatures, and into those five great elements all
creatures resolve themselves, repeatedly, like the infinite waves of
the Ocean rising from the Ocean and subsiding into that which causes
them. .... Verily, sound springs from Space, and all dense matter is
the attribute of earth. Life is from Wind. Taste is from Water. Form
is said to be the property of Light. ....... The Creator places in
all creatures the same five great essences in proportions that He
thinks proper. Sound, the ears, and all cavities,--these
three,--have Space for their producing cause. Taste, all watery or
juicy substances, and the tongue, are said to be the properties of
water. Form, the eye, and the digestive fire in the stomach, are said
to partake of the nature of Light. Scent, the organ of smelling, and
the body, are the properties of earth. Life, touch, and action are
said to be the properties of Wind.
[Section 286, Mokshadharma Parva, Santi Parva, The Mahabharata]

The question is about experiencing this connection. Is it possible to understand the relationship between the mahabhootas and tanmatras solely at a physical level, or are there spiritual practices, perhaps through yoga or other means, that can help experience this relationship?
